# How to transform quadratic function's output range to be negative for its negative input domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function $f(x) = x^2$ normally gives a range of output values that are all non-negative, $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

How can the function be transformed so that when $x<0$, the output $f(x)$ values are also negative, without resorting to a piece-wise function? In other words, flip the left hand side of the function across the x-axis, without altering the right hand side.

Comment: Excuse me, but what you said will happen if it is $f(x) = x^3$, right ?

Comment: no, that function looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#/media/File:Polynomialdeg3.svg

Comment: ok... thanks...

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ returns negative values for imaginary numbers (those with that $i$ part in them)

Comment: If that's not what you want : sorry that I wasn't of any help.

Comment: thanks but imaginary numbers won't be used as inputs

Comment: Surely. And I am sorry for not being sufficiently helpful.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2\cdot \operatorname{sign}(x)$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Here is a similar non-negative function of the same shape: how can the same transformation be done to it? $-\frac{1}{2} \ln (1-x^2)$

Comment: Very similarly: multiply it by $sign (x)$.

Comment: @badjohn here is a follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817051/how-to-derive-variable-from-equation-containing-log-and-sign-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x^2 & x\geq 0 \\
      -x^2 &x\lt 0 
   \end{cases}
$$
But since you don't want it a piecewise function you can write it as:
$$f(x)=x\cdot |x|$$
Or as:
$$f(x)=\text{sign}(x)\cdot x^2$$
This will preserve the values of $f(x)$ when $x\geq0$, and will flip its values when $x\lt0$.

Comment: shouldn't the second formula be $f(x) = x^2 \times \text{sign}(x)$?

Comment: Both $sign(x)x^2$ and $x.|x|$ are correct for your question. I assumed you wanted to use elementary functions and avoid $sign(x)$, since you didn't want to use piecewise functions.

Comment: that period you have really means $x \times |x|$?

Comment: yes, the period is the same as $\times$

Comment: here is a follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817051/how-to-derive-variable-from-equation-containing-log-and-sign-function