# How to calculate the inverse function of $y=-\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-x^2) \times \text{sign}(x)$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, inverse-function

How can the continuous random variable $x$ by isolated by itself on one side of the following equation

$$y = -\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-x^2) \times \text{sign}(x)$$

without resorting to a piece-wise equation?

$$ x = ?$$

Below is my initial, incomplete and probably wrong attempt since I don't know the exponential of a product or the exponential of $\text{sign}()$:

$$ -2 y = \ln(1-x^2) \times \text{sign}(x)$$
$$ \exp(-2y) = (1-x^2) \times \exp(\text{sign}(x))$$

Comment: The function is an odd function, so you can do it just for $x>0$, whence we just have $y = -\frac 12\ln(1-x^2)$.(The square root , when eventually taken to determine $x$ will be positive).

Comment: the derivation without the sign multiplier is easy and well-known, so I would like to learn how to do it for the function shown instead ($x\in \mathbb{R}$ not just $x>0$)

Comment: The domain of $y$ is $x \in (-1,1)$,since otherwise $\ln (1-x^2)$ would be undefined. My comment still stands : break $y$ into a piecewise function by breaking the $\mbox{sign}$ into one, then find the piecewise inverses and put them together. In a follow up question you have asked for the derivative : you can get it everywhere except at $0$ where you need to create the differential quotient. The sign multiplier is handled by breaking the function into pieces, so that on each piece we know what to do.

Comment: is it possible to isolate $x$ without resorting to piece-wise functions, I meant to add that to the question and will do so now

Comment: @TeresaLisbon question is edited with attempted derivation for someone to come through on

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I now see what you want to do. Here's something : note that $sign(x) = sign(y(x))$ for all $x$ (proved by noting that $\frac{sign(x)}{x} = \frac 1{|x|}$ is always positive for $x \neq 0$, so the quotient $\frac{y}{x}$ is also always positive for $x \neq 0$), so you can replace $sign(x)$ with $sign(y)$. This should help. Let us discuss this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112746/discussion-between-develarist-and-teresa-lisbon).

Comment: Using $\text{sgn}(x)$ is just hiding the piecewise logic.  How do you define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

1. $x \geq 0$:
   \begin{align*}
   y&=-\frac{1}{2}ln(1-x^2)\\
   -2y &= ln(1-x^2)\\
   e^{-2y} &= 1-x^2\\
   x^2 &= 1-e^{-2y}\\
   x &= +\sqrt{1-e^{-2y}} \qquad :\text{since } x \geq 0
   \end{align*}
2. $x < 0$:
   \begin{align*}
   y&=\frac{1}{2}ln(1-x^2)\\
   2y &= ln(1-x^2)\\
   e^{2y} &= 1-x^2\\
   x^2 &= 1-e^{2y}\\
   x &= -\sqrt{1-e^{2y}} \qquad :\text{since } x < 0
   \end{align*}

Now, as stated in the comments, you notice that $y(x)$ has the same sign as $x$, i.e: $$\text{sign}(x) = \text{sign}(y(x))$$
So, the different formulas for $x$ can be unified using $\text{sign}(y)$, as follows:
$$x=\text{sign}(y)\sqrt{1-e^{-2y.\text{sign}(y)}}$$
Also, since  $y.\text{sign}(y)=|y|$, we can write $x$ as:
$$x=\text{sign}(y)\sqrt{1-e^{-2|y|}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use chain rule noting that for $x\neq 0$

$$(\text{sign}(x))'=0$$

therefore

$$(f(x)\cdot \text{sign}(x))'=f'(x)\cdot \text{sign}(x)$$

Comment: this omits all the actual content of the function and is incomplete since $x$ is not isolated, could you show the line-by-line operations without masking with chain rule

Comment: what's the problem? The $sign$ function is $1$ for x >0 and $-1$ for $x <0$

Comment: @Tortar what does that mean for the first derivative of $\text{sign}(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

From

$$y=-\frac12\ln(1-x^2)\text{ sgn}(x)$$ we can draw

$$x=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1-e^{-2y\text{ sgn(x)}}}$$
because the square root is a positive number. But the function is odd, $\text{sgn}(x)=\text{sgn}(y)$, and

$$x=\text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{1-e^{-2|y|}}.$$

Comment: doesn't differenting the equation cause an unwanted called $y'$? I would like to retain $y$ as is while isolating $x$

Comment: you singled out a single component of the equation while ignoring two others: $y$ and $\text{sign}(x)$. if i take the derivative of the entire equation, i have to deal with a new quantity called $y'$, which is the first derivative of variable $y$. I would like to retain $y$ *as is*, while isolating $x$

Comment: read the question again, especially the first two formulas

Comment: @develarist: oops, sorry, because of the other answer, I was on the way of a differentiation question. That was silly !